# How do I communicate with a GPIO USB device in OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, usb, device, iokit

I have a USB web camera from ViMicro that contains a GPIO chip.  We have a microswitch wired to one of the IO pins and can read the status of the switch on Windows using an ActiveX control that was provided by ViMicro, named `exvmuvc.ax`.  I need to duplicate this functionality using IOKit on OS X.

USBTrace from SysNucleus displays the conversation happening between the Windows system and the USB device, but I cannot duplicate this on the Mac.

Does anyone know of a software USB sniffer, like USBTrace, that works on OS X so that I can compare the packets?  Also, is anyone familiar with this particular camera chip and its GPIO subsystem, even on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You could use usbtracer from Xcode, or you can try using using USB Prober with a [debug release of IOUSBFamily](http://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/download/usbdebug.html), this will most likely output more information than you actually want. You may want to look at [qa1370](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1370/_index.html) for more information.

In general though, I'd recommend you get a hardware USB analyzer, they make this sort of thing much easier.